Stored procedure not running after 10 minutes
I am working with C# and SQL Server.
I am calling a long-running stored procedure in SQL Server from C# using the System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand class.

The SQL Server's remote query timeout (server configuration option) is set to 1200 seconds i.e. 20 minutes.
The CommandTimeout property of SqlCommand class is set to 0 which means it will never timeout.

I call the stored procedure from C# using the statement command.ExecuteNonQuery();.
After 10 minutes are passed, the stored procedure stop executing and I get an exception in C# :

The requested operation cannot be completed because the connection has been broken.

My question is: where is this 10 minutes limitation coming from, and how to increase it?

The error is telling you the connection was broken, which means you have a bad network, or something else is killing your query, not timeouts
